# Unordered summation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, self-learning

I have a question regard unordered sumation.

**Definitions**: Let $X$ be a set (possible uncountable) and let $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. We say that $\sum _{x\in X}f(x)$ converges absolutely iff ${\; \text{  sup}}\big\{\sum _{x\in F}|f(x)|:F\subset X; \#F<\infty \big\}<\infty$. We define the sumation over $X$ as follows:

$$\sum _{x\in X}f(x):= \sum _{\{x\in X:f(x)\not=0\}}f(x)$$

It is not difficult to show that this is well-defined since ${\{x\in X:f(x)\not=0\}}$ is at most countable

Let $X$ be a countable set and let $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. If  $\sum _{x\in X}f(x)$ converges absolutely, we define

$$\sum _{x\in X}f(x):= \sum _{i=0}^{\infty}f(\alpha(i))$$

For some bijective map $\alpha: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$.

---

**Lemma**: Let $X$ be a set (possible uncountable) and let $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be functions such that $\sum _{x\in X}f(x)$ and $\sum _{x\in X}g(x)$ converges absolutely (2). Then $\sum _{x\in X}f(x)+g(x)$ converges absolutely. Moreover $\sum _{x\in X}f(x)+g(x)=\sum _{x\in X}f(x)+\sum _{x\in X}g(x)$ (2).

Proof:

(1) The absolutely convergent is rather easy and really only matters me the second part.

(2) Let $A=\{x\in X: f(x)\not=0 \text{ or } g(x)\not=0\}$, then we claim that the series 
$\sum_{x\in A}f(x)$ is convergent. This follows since $A\subset X$ and we know that $\sum_{x\in X}f(x)$ is absolute convergent then former must converges absolutely and so converges conditionally.

Claim 1: $\sum _{x\in A} f(x)= \sum _{x\in X} f(x)$. Since by definition we have that:

$$\sum _{x\in A} f(x)=\sum _{x\in A:f(x)\not=0} f(x)  \text{ and } \sum _{x\in X} f(x)=\sum _{x\in X:f(x)\not=0} f(x)$$

It will suffice to show that $\{x\in A: f(x)\not=0\}=\{x\in X:f(x)\not=0\} $. But this follows immediately by construction of $A$.

A similar result holds for $g(x)$.

Claim 2:   $\sum _{x\in A} f(x) + g(x)= \sum_{x\in X}f(x) + g(x)$

It will suffice to show that $\{x\in A: f(x) + g(x)\not= 0 \} = \{x\in X: f(x) + g(x)\not= 0\}$. ($\Rightarrow$) is trivial. For ($\Leftarrow$) if $f(x) + g(x)\not= 0$ so either one of them is non zero so is in $A$ and also in the set.

Suppose WLOG that the set $A$ is countable infinite. Then there exists a bijective map $\alpha: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$, so

$$\sum _{x\in A} f(x) + g(x)= \sum_{i=0}^\infty f(\alpha(i))+g(\alpha(i))$$

Since by claim 1 we have

$$\sum_{x\in X} f(x)= \sum_{x\in A} f(x)= \sum_{i=0}^\infty f(\alpha(i))\, \text{ and }\, \sum_{x\in X} g(x)= \sum_{x\in A} g(x)= \sum_{i=0}^\infty g(\alpha(i))$$

So we have

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(\alpha(i))+g(\alpha(i))= \sum_{i=0}^\infty f(\alpha(i))+\sum_{i=0}^\infty g(\alpha(i))$$

and we're done. I think this works =)

Comment: Why ${\{x\in X:f(x)\not=0\}}$ is at most countable ?

Comment: Since converges absolutely. Then the set $\{x\in X: |f(x)|\ge 1/n \}$ are finite for each $n$ and the union of countable set is countable and the union is the desired set.

Comment: If we set $M$ as the value which the serie converges absolutely then each of the above set contain at most $M n$ elements.

Comment: Take $A = \{ x : f(x)\neq 0 \text{ or } g(x) \neq 0\}$. Then $$\sum_{x\in X} f(x) = \sum_{x\in A} f(x)$$ and ditto for $g$.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer: But that assertion which is obvious need a proof and using  the definition as in my book is not, at least for me, take a bijective map from either a finite set of the natural numbers or  all the natural numbers to A and X  and show the equivalence. And after this show that $A$ is equivalent to the way is defined the sum in my book.